# Samsung alarm manager woes

Tags: kotlin, alarmmanager, samsung-galaxy

My app that was working fine on the Galaxy Z Flip3 phone quit working following an update from Samsung.  Now nothing I've tried results in an alarm notification unless the phone stays awake with the app as the focus (which requires keeping the phone plugged in, hardly a viable solution).  The phone has the ability under Battery and device care to set an app to never sleep, but the phone now seems to be ignoring that (I discovered this feature during my previous flailing, and it cured the identical problem at that time).

Here is the setAlarm code which includes the various options I've tried, commented out:

```kotlin
    fun setAlarm(timeInMillis: Long) {
        val alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val intent = Intent(this, MyAlarm::class.java)
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE)
        //alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
        //alarmManager!!.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
/*
        alarmManager!!.setAlarmClock(
            AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(
                timeInMillis,
                null
            ), pendingIntent )
*/
        /*
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                if(System.currentTimeMillis()<startTime)
                    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startTime, pendingIntent);
            } else {
                if(System.currentTimeMillis()<startTime)
                    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startTime, pendingIntent);
            }
        } else {
            if(System.currentTimeMillis()<startTime)
                alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startTime, pendingIntent);
        }

         */
        toastGeneral("""Alarm is set""")`
```

Does anyone know what Samsung has done, and what work arounds might exist to get the alarmManager to work again?
Thanks

Additional information that I've discovered:  If I set the alarm and turn off the screen (with the power button) the alarm will always fire even if it's hours away.  However, if I set the alarm and then return to the home screen (or any other app), the alarm won't fire even if it's just a few minutes away; then, when I select the app again, it immediately acts as though the alarm just fired.  There must be a difference in the state of the app under these conditions; does anyone know what it is, and how I can get the alarm to fire when it's in this different state?

9/15/23 It's now been a month since I posted this, and although over 100 people have seen it, no one has commented.  Does anyone have a kotlin app using Samsung's One UI 5.1.1 on a Flip phone that properly wakes up the app?  If so, could you please post the code that works?  Thanks.